# inject variables into the scope of a function

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

the following function takes an object and returns a function. the function it returns is a higher order function that takes a callback function.

```js
const deconstruct = function (object) {
    const declarations = Object.entries(object).reduce(function (string, entry) {
        const key = entry[0];
        const value = entry[1];
        const declaration = "const " + key + " = " + value + ";";
        return string + declaration;
    }, "");
    const execute = function (callback) {
        return Function(
            declarations
            + "return "
            + callback.toString()
            + "();"
        )();
    };
    return execute;
};
```

`execute` augments `callback` by making it part of a new function. the new function declares constants, runs `callback` and returns the result. because in the new function the constants declared and `callback` are in the same scope, `callback` can access those constants, thus effectively injecting those constants into the scope of `callback`. here’s an example of an invocation of `deconstruct`.

```js
deconstruct({
    a: 0,
    b: 1,
    c: 2
})(function () {
    console.log(a, b, c); // 0 1 2
});
```

but is there a different way to inject variables into the scope of a function without using intermediary strings like my code does?

Comment: I think you mean this `deconstruct(callback, ...outArgs) { return (function(inArgs) { callback(inArgs) })(outArgs); }`

Comment: Might I ask why you would want to do this? Seems like it'd be hard to figure out what variables are and aren't defined when using this.

Comment: I'd like to know why `({a, b, c}) => console.log(a, b, c)` isn't good enough for you.

Comment: @Khauri i don’t know actually. i was just answering somebody else’s question and that was my answer. i was just wondering if there were any way to improve it. here’s the link to the original question: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/f5mrnl/object_destructure_to_variables_can_we_get_more/fi1hpam/

Comment: @Wyck i don’t know actually. i was just answering somebody else’s question and that was my answer. i was just wondering if there were any way to improve it. here’s the link to the original question: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/f5mrnl/object_destructure_to_variables_can_we_get_more/fi1hpam/

Comment: The problem with your solution is that since you are essentially re-defining the function, and the scope of a function is determined when the function is created, you end up losing the scope of the original function. You only maintain the global scope and the new scope you defined.

Comment: Although, I can potentially seeing what you wrote being used as an obfuscation trick in a CTF or something nefarious. JS sure has some surprising "features"

Comment: It seems the intent of the `console.log` is only to demonstrate that all the variables are in scope and the goal of the challenge is to avoid repeating the property names anywhere.  Am I right about that?  Is that what you're asking? If so then my new answer applies.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the approach in this example doesn't inject into an existing function, it's making a new function with `Function` (tantamount to `eval`).  Also, this won't work with an arrow function.

Comment: @Wyck yeah `console.log` is only there to demonstrate how you can access and call object properties by their names. and true, i was hesitant to use `Function` but i didn’t know what else to do since the OP wanted me to not use a `with`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your revised information in the question, I see now that the purpose was to keep it DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).  The goal was to avoid repeating (a,b,c) unnecessarily, imagining that there may be hundreds of properties.

Here's one strategy.  You could make use of the `with` statement to bring `this` into scope and bind the object to the function.

```js
values = { a: 0, b: 1, c: 2 };

function foo() {
  with(this) {
    console.log(a,b,c);
  }
}

foo.apply(values);

// or

let bar = foo.bind(values);
bar();
```

Or for a one-time use, you can just define the function with the values in scope:

```js
values = { a: 0, b: 1, c: 2 };

with (values) foo = () => {
  console.log(a, b, c);
}

foo();
```

Comment: thanks! it’s better than my solution. though i didn’t use a with because the OP of the original question said they’d like to see a version without it, but i guess there isn’t much else i can do without it. their question was less of a practical question and more of a thought exercise anyway. i guess this is as good as one could make it. selected your answer! huge thanks for your help 